# VPN connection in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, vpn

I am trying to connect my DB with JMeter (JDBC Connection) but VPN is required to access the DB. I have VPN details with me but know how can I connect with my DB using JMeter?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you have active VPN connection (like the machine you're running JMeter on is connected to the VPN at the moment of test execution) you don't need to do anything, JMeter will be able to connect to the database.

If you don't want to have the VPN connection up all the time and looking for the way of connecting to the VPN prior to executing your test you can:

1. Use [setUp Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) and [OS Process Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter/) to establish the VPN connection before your main [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)(s) containing JDBC Test Elements start
2. Eventually you might go for [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) to disconnect the VPN after main Thread Group(s) execution end.